# iOS - File Input - Variable Typecasting Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, types

Inputing a JSON file into Core Data using the following code I found on cimgf.com:

```
NSString *filePathGPS = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gps_6kb" ofType:@"json"];


if (filePathGPS) {
    NSString *contentOfFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePathGPS encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [contentOfFile objectFromJSONString];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *areaName = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Area"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSDictionary *attributes = [[areaName entity] attributesByName];

    for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
        for (NSDictionary * tempDict in jsonDict) {
            NSLog(@"Attribute =  %@", attribute);

            id value = [tempDict objectForKey:attribute];

            NSLog(@"Value =  %@", value);

            if (value == nil) {
                continue;
            }


            [areaName setValue:value forKey:attribute];
        }
    }


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
2013-01-12 12:11:09.548 SuperGatherData[1194:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "area2"; desired type = NSString; given type = NSNull; value = <null>.'
```

I get why the error is occurring, because some of the values in the file are null and not strings. Here's a sample of the JSON data:

```
   {
        "area1": "International",
        "area2": null,
        "area3": null,
        "area4": null,
        "area5": null,
        "latitude": "-25.2447",
        "longtitude": "133.9453",
    },
    {
        "area1": "Alaska",
        "area2": "Anchorage & South Central Alaska ",
        "area3": null,
        "area4": null,
        "area5": null,
        "latitude": "61.2134",
        "longtitude": "-149.8672",
    },
    {
        "area1": "Alabama",
        "area2": null,
        "area3": null,
        "area4": null,
        "area5": null,
        "latitude": "34.4112",
        "longtitude": "-85.5737",
    },
```

and realize I need to do something with the typecasting of attribute in the following line:

```
for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
```

I just have no idea what that fix is. I'm new to Objective-C and haven't dealt with strongly typed languages before.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with typecasting, that's just for fooling the compiler. Read up on why Objective-C is a dynamic language and come back after you understood that.

Comment: Well, I realize now that the error has to do with the line `[areaName setValue:value forKey:attribute];`, and that the IF statement above to skip nil values is not skipping the values as it should. Still don't know why.

Comment: I suspect `if (value == nil) ` should be `if ([value isEqual:[NSNull null]])` instead.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! I'm alternating coding/reading documentation and now I'm going to step back and read some more documentation.

Comment: I made this an answer, please accept/upvote if it helped, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (value == nil)` should be `if ([value isEqual:[NSNull null]])` instead - most JSON parsers represent an explicit `null` value by `NSNull`, since one can't store `nil` in an `NSDictionary` nor in an `NSArray`.